# Automate external hive/athena table partition management

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bigdata, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I currently have a big data architecture where some data pipelines generates data output and stores it on AWS S3. I also have an internal metadata store where I keep a track of each S3 url and the status (indicating if the URL is valid or not).

There is a scheduled AWS glue crawler that crawls the S3 prefix and adds newly generated S3 paths as new partitions to the associated external athena table. So the data in my external table is automatically refreshed and available for query. This works fine.

Here is a new requirement that I want to integrate with this architecture - 
Users can mark some of the S3 URLs as invalid in the self managed metastore and I want to automatically delete those partitions from my external table.

Wondering what can be the best approach to solve this?

Eg: Consider there are 50 URLs in the S3 bucket and it is reflected in the self managed metastore as below - 
[image]

Seems like even if I drop the partitions by querying the megastore for invalid partitions they will show up again the next time that glue crawler runs. Is moving/deleting data from the S3 prefix the only option here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Glue crawler works well if you have a simple process and don't require a lot of flexibility or customization. I like it as a starting point. I'm not convinced it works well for a complex system.

In this case I'd turn off the Glue crawler. You're right - the crawler will simply re-add those dropped partitions.

- You can very easily [add](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html) and [drop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-drop-partition.html) partitions from an Athena table using `ALTER TABLE`.
- Explicitly invoke the `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` command when a new file is dropped.
- This is super simple - have a Lambda function listen to S3's object created event.

  1. The object is dropped and the event fires
  2. Lambda function starts and sees the object key
  3. Invokes an Athena query to add the new object as a partition.
- Explicitly invoke the `ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION` command when a user marks to remove.

The only thing to note is that I believe that Athena partitions need to be 'folders', i.e. the location of a partition needs to end in a `/`, and you can't add a single file as a partition. Any file that is added within a 'folder' that Athena knows about will be added to any query. You may need to revise your file structure (based on the sample you've posted) if that is the case.